# QML: Crash when using getFormattedText of TextArea

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, richtext

QuickControls 2.4
Qt 5.11.3

I am trying to get formatted text (RichText) from TextArea, but when calling the getFormattedText function more than 5 times (always in different ways) everything breaks and an error appears

> pure virtual method called 
> terminate called without an active exception

Even if there are a couple of letters in the field, the function still fails.

```
onClicked: console.log(codeArea.getFormattedText(0,length))
```

Comment: Hang on, what's wrong with reading `codeArea.text` ?

Comment: it breaks down too(, getText ( Without Formating ) works

Comment: Please provide a [mre].